# JavaFX Button with multiple text lines

Tags: java, button, javafx, javafx-8, multiline

I need to create a toolbar in my screen that will have multiple buttons, and each button must have multiple lines of Text. For example:

[image: Button with multiple lines]

I looked over the internet and StackOverflow but I couldn't find anything showing how to do this in JavaFX. I'm using JavaFX 8.

Someone could help me, please?

Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem including a VBox inside my button, and then including several Labels inside the VBox. Like this:

[image]

The result is:

[image]

If there is a more elegant way to have the same result, please, let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: When I did this the toString method of the VBox was called.

Answer (score 9):

Also you can use the `wrapTextProperty`. But you have to set toolbar height greater than expected button height.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.wrapTextProperty().setValue(true);
// or btn.setWrapText(true);
btn.setText("Some looooooooooooong text");
```

Or if you want to determine exactly where the line should be wrapped, you can go this way:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Line1\n Line2\n Line3");
```

Last way will work without changing toolbar height.

Answer (score 3):

In the button text property select "switch to multi-line mode

[image]"

Comment: nice suggestion :) tnx

Comment: or if you generate you button dynamically, in code button.setWrapText(true);

Answer (score 1):

From sobolev's response, you can do:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Line1\n Line2\n Line3");
button.textAlignmentProperty().set(TextAlignment.CENTER);
```

This will create 3 lines of text and allign them in the center of your button.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty much the same as the one given by the OP, but instead of `Label` uses `Text` so it's more flexible to changes in the size of the button, as it will use as many lines as needed. If required, also one can set a wrapping width, to define a width constraint.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(<image>).toExternalForm()));
    Text text=new Text("Some long text that may be line wrapped");
    text.setWrappingWidth(100);
    VBox vBox = new VBox(5, imageView,text);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    btn.setGraphic(vBox);
    btn.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label label= new Label("your long text here");
label.setStyle("-fx-max-width : 180px);
label.setWrapText(true);
```