# How to Display all the text in Buttons in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to display all the text in the JavaFX which should display all the texts in the font:
This is my javafx code

```
<HBox> 
<GridPane xmlns:fx= "http://javafx.com/fxml" hgap = "10" vgap = "0">

<Button text = "Explore Catalogue" alignment = "center" styleClass = "largeButton" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
<Button text = "Customer Record" styleClass = "largeButton" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
<Button text = "Top-up Account" styleClass = "largeButton" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
<Button text = "Favourite Movies" styleClass = "largeButton" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>



</GridPane>
```

This code is only able to give this output:
[image]
How do I display all the texts in the button without changing the font properties which should look like this:
[image]
my css code for the button is:

```
.largeButton {
-fx-font-family: "Verdana";
-fx-pref-width: 200px;
-fx-pref-height: 200px;
-fx-font-size: 28px;
-fx-background-color: white;
-fx-text-fill: #4d4b44;
-fx-border-color: #dedede;
```

}

Comment: Did you try `-fx-wrap-text: true;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `-fx-wrap-text: true;` in your css stylsheets, it will do the trick. This css property is inherited from `Labeled` and enable to wrap the text (surprinsingly) smartly (first the white spaces).

```
.largeButton {
    -fx-font-family: "Verdana";
    -fx-pref-width: 200px;
    -fx-pref-height: 200px;
    -fx-font-size: 28px;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: #4d4b44;
    -fx-border-color: #dedede;
    -fx-wrap-text : true;
}
```

[image]

**Edit**

This also could be done by code with `myLargeButton.setWrapText(true)` or by adding this directly in your FXML file by adding `wrapText="true"`which will give you :

```
<Button text = "Favourite Movies" wrapText="true" styleClass = "largeButton" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
```

But doing this by the css stylesheet is recommanded here for clarity purpose and also because you already have one.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `wrapText="true"` to your buttons like
`<Button text = "Explore Catalogue" wrapText="true" ... />`

Or check here: [JavaFX Button with multiple text lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27295505/javafx-button-with-multiple-text-lines)